# How to do a Swipe down refresh animation on jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, swipe, swipe-gesture

I'm developing a web application for the first time, and I'm looking to do a swipe down refresh animation just to make the page reload again, I'm using Javascript and jQueryMobile for my Web App.

Is there any library ? or any easy method I can use

[image: Swipe down to Refresh]

Comment: What did you try? Post some codes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a thing you can use...apparently theres a newer version out, i tried the example and it works http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Here is the example http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/pull-to-refresh/

Found on this post [Pull down to refresh on mobile web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306328/pull-down-to-refresh-on-mobile-web-browser)