# How to implement the lazy loading for listing of multiple records like Gmail app loading in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

We are getting n number of records at a time when hit the web service due to this performance of the app was too slow, so I need to implement lazy loading in my app to show the n number of records as like as Gmail app functionality using lazy loading to increase the performance of my app.

Comment: It's hard to guess what you are doing off this description but make sure you aren't violating the EDT when fetching data. See the property cross demo where a search returns elements in an infinite scrolling list.

Comment: Actually,we have 1000(Example) number of records to show as list  , for this we are getting all the 1000 records at a time due to this performance of the device was too slow, so i need to get the 10 records for first time ,when i scroll it to top then after i need to get next 10 records simultaneously . So Please help me to implement this functionality

Comment: @Sivaji Vithanala, are you developing in Web or mobile? In which platform? Here is some information in web http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306328/pull-down-to-refresh-on-mobile-web-browser

Comment: @ Zin Min ,Am developing Android and ios Apps

Comment: Please update your question to provide more details about what you are trying to achieve, and what specific problems you are having now.  How many records are you trying to load now?  How was the performance bad?  (Was the app locking up, hanging etc..)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to retrieve records batch by batch? 
If yes, you can use page by page view or pull-to-refresh technic.